# Morphisms between supermanifolds R^{0|1}→R^{0|1}

Tags: supermanifolds

I am confused with morphisms of supermanifolds. Take a simple example $f:R^{0|1}\to R^{0|1}$. By (one of) definition, $f$ is a morphism of superalgebras of functions $C(R^{0|1})\to C(R^{0|1})$. Morphisms of superalgebras preserve the grading, I deduced that $f$ have the form $1\mapsto 1, \theta\mapsto x\theta$, i.e. $Hom(R^{0|1}\to R^{0|1})=R^1$ (as a set?). But I read from a paper that $Hom(R^{0|1},R^{0|1})=R^{1|1}$. What is going on? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right that the set of supermanifold morphisms 
$Hom(\mathbb R^{0|1},\mathbb R^{0|1})$ to itself is $\mathbb R^1$. 
However, one can define for supermanifolds $X,Y$ with $\dim X=0|d$ a 
supermanifold $map(X,Y)$ of morphisms from $X$ to $Y$, by $Hom(Z,map(X,Y))=Hom(Z\times X,Y)$ for all supermanifolds $Z$.

And $map(\mathbb R^{0|1},\mathbb R^{0|1})=\mathbb R^{1|1}$.

Comment: Very interesting! I reread the paper, it says actrually inter-hom, maybe it your $map$. Should it be $X=R^{0|d}$?

Comment: @Ma: Yes, the inner hom is the same thing as map.  Which paper are you reading, by the way?

Comment: As @Ma Ming said, it suffices that $X$ be $0|\delta$-dimensional for $\operatorname{Maps}(X,Y)$ to be finite-dimensional.  However, it's not good enough for $Y$ to be $0|\delta$-dimensional.  For example, $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb R^{1|1},\mathbb R^{0|1}) = \operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb R[\epsilon], \mathcal C^\infty(\mathbb R)[\epsilon])$, where $\epsilon^2 = 0$ and $\epsilon$ is in odd degree; but such a map is any $\epsilon \mapsto f(x)\epsilon$, so this hom space is infinite-dimensional $\mathcal C^\infty(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: Thank you all! Could you give a clue how to calculate the $map$, for example, $map(R^{0|d},M)$ for any supermanifold $M$?

Answer (score 2):

@Ma: As an answer to your following question:

> Could you give a clue how to calculate the $map$, for example, $map(R^{0∣d},M)$ for any  supermanifold $M$?

Take a look at arXiv:math/0307303, where this question is discussed.

For $d=1$, it is well-known (and due to Kontsevich, I think), that $map(R^{0|1},M)$ is the total space of the odd tangent bundle $\Pi TM$ of $M$.

If $U$ is a superdomain of dimension $p|q$, then $map(R^{0|d},U)=U\times R^{pr+qs|ps+qr}$ where $(r+1)|s=2^{d-1}|2^{d-1}$ is the graded dimension of $\bigwedge R^d$. This you can check using the definition of $map$ and the characterisation of morphisms of supermanifolds as given in Leites.

Another good source on this subject (for $d=1$), is the paper "Differential forms and 0-dimensional supersymmetric field theories" by Hohnhold, Kreck, Stolz and Teichner.

Comment: Clickable arxiv:math/0307303:  [Kochan and Severa - Differential gorms, differential worms](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0307303) (not a typo, I think!).